# Linear maps (about rank and nullity)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $S:U\rightarrow V$ and $T:V\rightarrow W$ are linear maps.
>
> $U,V$ and $W$ are vector space over the same field.
>
> Prove: If $V=W$ and $T$ is non-singular then $\mathrm{Rank}(TS)=\mathrm{Rank}(S)$

Attempt of this question:
$V=W$ so $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$

Since $T$ is non-singular so $\mathrm{Rank}(T)=\dim(V)$

$T(V)$ is a subspace of $W$ so it is also a subspace of $V$

Then $T(V)$ is the whole space of $W$

What I can do to show $T(S(u))=S(u)$ in order to show $\mathrm{Rank}(TS)=\mathrm{Rank}(S)$ ?

Comment: Did you mean $S:U\rightarrow V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compose linear maps, the rank cannot increase:
\begin{align}\def\rk{\operatorname{rank}}
&\rk(TS)\le\rk(S)\tag{1}\\
&\rk(TS)\le\rk(T)\tag{2}
\end{align}
Since $T$ is nonsingular, you also have
$$
S=T^{-1}TS
$$
and so
$$
\rk(S)=\rk(T^{-1}(TS))\le\rk(TS)
$$
by $(2)$. Since $\rk(TS)\le\rk(S)$ by $(1)$, we're done.

Answer (score 1):

$T(S(u))\ne S(u)$ in general.

$T$, being non singular, is an isomorphism of linear space, so it preserves the dimension of subspaces it transforms.

So the $\mathrm{Rank}(S)$ is the dimension of the image of $S$. Such an image is transformed by $T$ in a subspace of the same dimension. Such transformed subspace is the image of $TS$, whose dimension is the $\mathrm{Rank}(TS)$.

Comment: why would the dimension of subspaces preserves here?

Answer (score 0):

Isomorphisms of linear spaces are homomorphisms so they preserve linear combination. A non singular linear map does not degenerate, that is it gives the null vector only when applied to a null vector. So all non-null linear combinations of linearly indipendent vectors (for them to be non-null they must have at least one coefficient not null) are mapped to non-null linear combinations with the same coefficients of the transformations of the original vectors. So such transformations are linearly indipendent. All that proves that the transformation of a subspace has a dimension at least equal to the dimension of the subspace itself.

The dimension of the transformation of a subspace through a homomorphism of a linear space cannot have a dimension strictly greater than the dimension of the subspace itself because bases in the transformation of the subspace are images of bases of the subspace itself. You cannot have more vectors in the base of the transformation of a subspace as there are in the base of the subspace itself because that would mean that the map is not a map, lacking the property of being single-valued.

Dimension preservation is so proved.

Please note: all that holds also for monomorphism of a linear space. So $\mathrm{Rank}(TS) = \mathrm{Rank}(S)$ also when $T$ is a monomorphism of linear space and not only when is an isomorphism.